# Поочерёдный вывод информации в shell_exec

Tags: php, shell

Есть test.php. Этот файл в течение какого то времени выводит какую то информацию (Когда вызываю его консоли то всё ок)

Но как мне запустить этот файл средствами php, чтобы тоже поочерёдно выводилась инфа ?
shell_exec('test.php') только один раз выводит инфу и всё

Comment: Можно использовать  [proc_open()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php) , там можно настроить каналы ввода и вывода, запускаешь test.php через нее, потом получаешь ресурс этого процесса и уходишь в цикл, в цикле работаешь с выводом данного скрипта сколько тебе нужно, т.е. допустим можно писать вывод в файл, а потом с файлом работать, это хороший способ, т.к. ты в целом сможешь контролировать работу этого скрипта, в нужный момент закрыть его

Comment: А как мне сохранить ресурс, чтобы потом из другого файла работать с ним?

Comment: Я запустил свой файл через proc_open, вроде всё работает отлично, идёт запись в файл. Вызываю функцию get_resources, а он пустой

Comment: Ресурс не получал, работал в цикле в этом же файле, в нужных мне файлах я обращался только к файлу вывода, что бы получить нужную информацию